# Does NTT have an upper bound?

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, fast-fourier-transform

I'm working with NTT (Number theoretic transform) to reduce the complexity of a polynomial multiplication. For this, I'm using $P = 2^{64}-2^{32}+1$ to generate the primitive root $\omega_N$ needed by the transform.

This technique works for some values, but fails for others. E.g., for N = 4, values bigger than $2^{63}-2^{31}$ breaks the transform, so that $INTT(NTT(x)) \neq x$. This threshold gets smaller as N increases, and I don't understand why.

What defines the upper bound for the input in this transform?

Comment: how do you prove that the NTT works ? (you'll get immediately when it doesn't)

Comment: Do you write your $x$ as a vector in $\mathbb{Z}_P^N$?

Comment: @Luckyluck63 Yes.

Comment: Related to this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141019/minimal-modulus-for-the-finite-field-ntt  ?

Comment: And maybe this one can help too: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437624/number-theoretic-transform-ntt-example-not-working-out